# Независимость формы от главного окна

Tags: winapi, delphi

Здравствуйте, уважаемые коллеги.

Поскольку со времени создания прошлого вопроса решения проблемы так и не нашлось, создаю новый. Есть моя DLL. Есть стороннее приложение, в которое я её внедряю. Если добавить в мою dll форму (стандартными средствами delphi), то форма получается зависимой от главного потока чужого приложения. Если главному потоку чужого приложения (а всего потоков там десятки) делать suspend, суспендится и моя форма. Ежели убить главный поток чужого приложения - скрывается/убивается и моя форма, хотя код моей библиотеки спокойно продолжает выполняться.

НО. Если я создаю форму на WINAPI (на сколько позволяют мои скудные познания этого api), всё прекрасно, форма независима от главного потока. Но описывать такую форму с теми элементами, с какими мне требуется, я замучаюсь, да и требуемую задачу тогда не решу.
Что со стандартной дельфийской формой не так? Где какое свойство подправить/поменять, чтобы форма создавалась независимой от главного потока чужого приложения?

Заранее большое спасибо за ответ и спасибо всем, кто дочитал мою писанину :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У библиотеки есть главная процедура main = секция begin end. Попробуйте в ней создавать поток обработки сообщении, в котором создается ваша форма.

Ключевые слова для поиска: [**Delphi Потоки DLL**](http://yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=Delphi+Потоки+DLL).

Если такие извращения вам не помогут, то я уже не знаю чем вам можно помочь.

Answer (score 2):

Полагаю, формы вы рисуете на [VCL](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Component_Library). Если не ошибаюсь, VCL компоненты сами по себе не могут существовать. Например, если элементы UI, созданные средствами WinAPI, рисуются самой ОС, то элементы VCL непосредственно ОС уже не рисуются, а рисуются средствами библиотеки (с использованием того же WinAPI).
*Возможно*, завершая главный поток, выгружается среда VCL, которая обеспечивает жизнидеятельность загруженных с dll форм. Смотря где и как загружаются эти формы?
*Если* формы, хранящиеся в dll, загружаются главным потоком, то получается, что для главного потока, формы являются всего лишь внешними ресурсами, которые естественно выгружаются, при завершении потока.
*Формы* должны загружаться в коде уже запущенного нового потока. Скорее всего, ваши формы загружаются не там, где нужно или не так, как нужно.
*Посмотрите* на WinAPI функции [CreateThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453(v=vs.85).aspx), [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx)... В dll хранить "новую программу" целиком, не только формы, но и коды (функция потока, др. подпрогр.), которые загружают формы. Потом ее можно будет запустить независимым потоком.